# Sequentially update mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, sequential

Given the following table, how can I sequentially reorder `position` from 1 to N using a single query after one or more rows have been deleted and still preserve the order of `position`?

```
+---------+----------+-----+
| id (pk) | position | fk  |
+---------+----------+-----+
|       4 |        1 | 123 |
|       2 |        2 | 123 |
|      18 |        3 | 123 |
|       5 |        4 | 123 |
|       3 |        5 | 123 |
+---------+----------+-----+
```

For instance, if `position`=1 (`id`=4) was deleted, the desired final records are:

```
+---------+----------+-----+
| id (pk) | position | fk  |
+---------+----------+-----+
|       2 |        1 | 123 |
|      18 |        2 | 123 |
|       5 |        3 | 123 |
|       3 |        4 | 123 |
+---------+----------+-----+
```

and if `position`=3 (`id`=18) was deleted, the desired final records are:

```
+---------+----------+-----+
| id (pk) | position | fk  |
+---------+----------+-----+
|       4 |        1 | 123 |
|       2 |        2 | 123 |
|       5 |        3 | 123 |
|       3 |        4 | 123 |
+---------+----------+-----+
```

I can do something like the following if only row was deleted but not for multiple rows.

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE fk=123 AND position = 4;
UPDATE mytable SET position=position-1 WHERE fk=123 AND position > 4;
```

Comment: What MySQL version do you use?

Comment: @RaymondNijland  Looking into 8.0.11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) to the rescue if you're not already using MySQL 8, which provides window functions like ROW_NUMBER():

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (

    SELECT 
    t.*
    , @n := @n + 1 as n
    FROM t
    , (SELECT @n := 0) var_init
    ORDER BY position

) sq ON t.id = sq.id
SET t.position = sq.n;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11d44f/1/0)

**BONUS:**

It gets slightly more complicated, when you have multiple groups.
For example, for sample data like this

```
|  id | position |  fk |
|-----|----------|-----|
|   4 |        1 | 123 |
|   2 |        2 | 123 |
|   5 |        4 | 123 |
|   3 |        5 | 123 |
|  40 |        1 | 234 |
|  20 |        2 | 234 |
| 180 |        3 | 234 |
|  30 |        5 | 234 |
```

the query would be

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (

    SELECT 
    t.*
    , @n := if(@prev_fk != fk, 1, @n + 1) as n
    , @prev_fk := fk
    FROM t
    , (SELECT @n := 0, @prev_fk := NULL) var_init
    ORDER BY fk, position

) sq ON t.id = sq.id
SET t.position = sq.n;
```

Here you just save the current fk in another variable. When the next row is processed, the variable still holds the value of the "previous row". Then you reset the `@n` variable, when the value changes.

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3216cd/1/0)

**UPDATE:**

In MySQL 8 you can use the window function `row_number()` like this:

```
update t join (
    select t.*, row_number() over (partition by fk order by position) as new_pos 
    from t
) sq using (id) set t.position = sq.new_pos;
```

Comment: Thanks fancyPants.  I don't have much experience with used user-defined variables.  What is `(SELECT @n := 0) var_init` doing?

Comment: It's just a subquery, in which you initialize the variable. You can leave this out and instead write `SET @n := 0; UPDATE...`. It would be the same.

Comment: Actually `(SELECT @n := 0) var_init`  is a `CROSS JOIN` where you initialize the variable.. + 1 for the answer indeed a good way to use MySQL user variables.

Comment: Yes, a subquery that is cross joined. Forgive me my sloppiness.

Comment: Yes, I do have multiple groups.  `position`/`fk` has a unique index on it.

Comment: It appears that your second example updates all records and not just those for a given `fk`, true?  If I wanted to just update all records with a given `fk`, would I just use your first example and add `WHERE fk=123` in the `SELECT` query?

Comment: @user1032531 Yes, just use first example. You can also use second example, just add the where clause before `order by fk, position`.

Comment: @user1032531 FYI, I updated my answer with an easier solution for MySQL 8, if you're using this already.

Answer (score 1):

You can use update and the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function. If you order by position you it should be ok.

```
UPDATE [1]
SET POSITION = [2].RN
FROM t [1]
JOIN (
       SELECT 
           t.ID
           , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY POSITION DESC) AS RN
       FROM t
     ) [2] 
ON [1].id = [2].id
```

As people have mentioned this is not applicable for MySql. Sorry for the missinformation as i didnt saw the tag.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` only works for MySQL 8.0.. And you are linking to SQL Server documentation..

Comment: Thanks dimo raichev.  Do you mind showing a typical query using `ROW_NUMBER()`?

Comment: This works on SQL Server not on MySQL.. MySQL follows  `UPDATE JOIN SET` order not `UPDATE SET JOIN`.. And after the update you are still linking to the SQL Server documentation for `ROW_NUMBER()`... Besides what is `[number]` is that BNF (Backus-Naur-vorm) where the table/column name should be added or are the brackets there for SQL Server escaping.. MySQL doesn't support brackets for escaping MySQL uses backticks for that

Comment: I edited my comment to state that it doesn't fit the question well, as i usualy browse the MSSQL tags. Sorry for the error. If people think it may confuse someone i can delete it.

Comment: No problem and still appreciated.